# console.log() is not working in any browser console- Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, console.log

Here is my code which i have used in my component.ts file.

```
export class AppComponent {

@ViewChild('f') signupForm: NgForm;
defaultQuestion = 'teacher';
answer = '';
genders = ['Male','Female']

onSubmit() {
 console.log(this.signupForm);
}
```

I Couldn't able to view the message in my console in any browser.
I have tried all the options like (slecting all options in the console, selecting only the logs etc).

Could some one help me with this

Comment: check that you have bind the onSubmit method in template

Comment: Put a "debugger;" above that console.log and this way you can know the control ever comes to that line. Open developer tools in your browser and check again.

Comment: <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm"> </form> This is the code i am using.